# DidReceiveRemoteNotification equivalent in Android?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is there an Android equivalent to the `DidReceiveRemoteNotification` method in iOS?

Scenario:  I would like to display a modal dialog box in an Android application when a user clicks on a remote notification to open the application.  In iOS, you can create a UIAlertView object in the `DidReceiveRemoteNotfiication` method to display the message detail in the same manner.

Answer (score 2):

There's `onReceive` method, which is equivalent to iOS's `DidReceiveRemoteNotfiication`. You can check it out [here (See -- Receive a Message Section)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

Comment: It there a way to determine that the application was opened by a notification in the `onReceive` method?